# Is it possible to have dynamic array of datatables in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

If it is, how to declare it? I tried a few different things, but none worked:

```
Dim indexTables() = New DataTable()
Dim indexTables() As New DataTable()
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to specify the size of the array, or else initialize it.  How about: `Dim indexTables() As DataTable = New DataTable() {}`, which initializes to an empty array. For reference: [VB Arrays definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) has lots of examples for how to declare arrays.

Comment: One option is to just create a `DataSet` and use its `Tables` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic arrays in VB.Net are not good, okay? If you use `ReDim Preserve` to change the size of an array anywhere in your .Net code, [you're a bad person and you should feel bad.](https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/You-Should-Feel-Bad-Zoidberg)

Instead, pretty much everywhere you currently think "dynamic array", you should think "generic list":

```
Dim indexTables As New List(Of DataTable)()
```

Now you can call `indexTables.Add()` to append a new DataTable whenever you need, and you can lookup DataTable objects in the collection by index or use it with a `For Each` loop, just like with an array.

Comment: Thanks. I should knew that already. Regards,